# Laravel Nova - Custom logic for Updating resources

Tags: laravel-nova

Is it possible to modify or add custom logic when you're updating, 
 creating and deleting resources?

If you, for example want to be able to update a subscription plan for your service through Nova but also need to send an API request to Stripe in order to update the plan there as well, how would you go about doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Laravel Nova is just a frontend for manipulating Eloquent models, I would do this using Laravel [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events) and [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the reply! :)